# Changing the item value in localStorage and dropdown list

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this javascript code,

```
function saveQ(){
var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
for(var s = 1; s < qs.length;s++){
 var ques = document.getElementById("eq"+qs[s]).value;
 localStorage.setItem(title+"_e"+qs[s],ques);
}
var existingEntries = localStorage.getItem("Tests");
var existingEntries2 = JSON.parse(existingEntries);
existingEntries2.push(title);
localStorage.setItem("Tests", JSON.stringify(existingEntries2));
listTest();
}
function listTest(){
    var t = localStorage.getItem("Tests");
    var tests2 = JSON.parse(t);
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('list');
    while (dropdown.firstChild) {
            dropdown.removeChild(dropdown.firstChild);
        }
    for(var i=0;i<tests2.length;i++){
        var o = document.createElement("option");
            o.value = tests[i];
            o.text = tests[i];
        dropdown.appendChild(o);
    }
}
```

If the save button is clicked, the function saveQ will be called.
Then the localStorage must be,

```
"["Blank Test","Personality Test","Basic Test","Sample Test"]"
```

Then the dropdown list will be changed.
The problem is why in the dropdown list, it is "undefined"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just an easy-to-make typo problem.

In your `for` loop in `listTest()`, you are referring to `tests[i]` instead of `tests2[i]`.